# How to merge a string Array and an Integer Array and add the corresponding values of the duplicates in the String Array

Tags: php

I want to merge two arrays and add the corresponding values of the duplicate strings.

My code is:

`$ids='f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf','f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf','26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac','26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac','6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f','6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f','c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3','c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3';
$ids2 ='1','8','1','4','6','1','3','1';
$ids = explode(',',$ids);
$ids2 = explode(',',$ids2);
$a = $ids;
$b = $ids2;
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
print_r($c);`

What I get is:

`Array ( ['f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf'] => '8' ['26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac'] => '4' ['6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f'] => '1' ['c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3'] => '1' )`

What I want is:

`Array ( ['f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf'] => '9' ['26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac'] => '5' ['6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f'] => '7' ['c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3'] => '4' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for keep all value of array $b for count it xD

```
function array_combine_($keys, $values)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
        $result[$k][] = $values[$i];
    }
    array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;'));
    return    $result;
}
$ids='f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf,f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf,26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac,26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac,6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f,6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f,c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3,c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3';

$ids2 ='1,8,1,4,6,1,3,1';

$ids = explode(',',$ids); $ids2 = explode(',',$ids2);

$a = $ids; $b = $ids2;
print_r(array_combine_($a, $b));
```

You will get result

```
Array ( 
    [f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 ) 
    [26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 ) 
    [6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 1 ) 
    [c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 ) )
```

Updated:
Use this code to get final array

```
$result = array_combine_($a, $b);
$new_result = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  $new_result[$key] = array_sum($value);
}
print_r($new_result);
```

Will get:

```
Array ( 
[f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf] => 9 
[26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac] => 5 
[6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f] => 7 
[c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3] => 4 )
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks alot, but how can i proceed from here to add up the values to get Array ( ['f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf'] => '9' ['26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac'] => '5' ['6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f'] => '7' ['c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3'] => '4' )

Comment: I had update my answer. Sorry but I think you can process it without my update.

Comment: You can echo array_sum($value) in foreach loop for testing. Source code working good with me.

Comment: Your $ids2 like with me? $ids2 ='1,8,1,4,6,1,3,1';

Comment: I don't see it :( It still Zero :(

Comment: final  question please, what if $ids='f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf,f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf,26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac,26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac,6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f,6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f,c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3,c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3,3016eb0233379ccf240d1ea10ec9178e';  and i want
Array ( ['3016eb0233379ccf240d1ea10ec9178e'] => 2 ['f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf'] => 9 ['26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac'] => 5 ['6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f'] => 7 ['c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3'] => '4' )
$ids2 ='1,8,1,4,6,1,3,1,2';

Comment: question is what if i add a single non duplicate string to the first  string array and a corresponding single integer to the second array and i want to get:     Array ( ['3016eb0233379ccf240d1ea10ec9178e'] => 2 ['f5522a8cc736750fffe1a9b7aa72c7bf'] => 9 ['26ba78d98033416372c3314c784f7aac'] => 5 ['6e983831ac2a73469abb7f94bdb8887f'] => 7 ['c6c5c00f7266ff3ca584662a0bc48bd3'] => '4' )

Comment: wow i fixed it i changed  array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;')); to  array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 0)? array_pop($v): $v;')); thanks alot, you are the very best